# How to add palm leaves to animated sapling tree

Tags: animation, armature, add-on, bones, sapling-addon

I'm trying to use the Sapling add-on to create and animate a palm tree with a certain large palm leaf. Creating the base palm tree is pretty straightforward after using the downward curves for the main branches.

I thought I could use the branches as the larger leaf stems then have the individual leaves come off those branches/stems.  The problem is getting these specific palm leaves right.  I don't think I can use the Sapling add-on for the individual leaves because the leaves have to be offset from both sides of the branches (or leaf stems).  So I'm trying to model the larger palm leaf and add it to the animated tree using the existing armature for the branches.  But I don't know if I can add my larger leaves to the existing armature.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.  Spent hours on this already.

Many thanks!

[image: palm leaf]

[image: palm tree]

[image: reference palm tree]

Comment: Load a reference image of what you are trying to do with the leaf arrangement...  This is of interest to me, too...

Comment: By the way, the way we do this now is SpeedTree... but there must be a solution....

Comment: Thanks, @rcgauer.  The sapling add-on seems to have gotten me (almost) where I need to be as far as the trunk branch structure - including the animation.  Just would need to mess with the trunk shape.  I have not looked very closely at the SpeedTree product due to the price tag.  But if you look at the models, the coconut palm and date palm have the types of leaves I'm going for.  Just can't figure out how to get these with sapling.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've got from a bit of playing with the sapling addon. It's not too detailed but it accomplishes having the leaves on both sides of the branch. The key setting here is under the "leaves" settings, set the "Leaf Rotation" to 180 degrees. This makes every alternate leaf appear on the opposite side of the branch.

[image]

[image]